# TypeScript causing React Native Jest tests to fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm integrating Jest into my react native app.  For some reason, the tests are failing due to a module that I'm using in the app.  react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view is causing the tests to fail because it is written in TypeScript.  The rest of the app is JS only.  Since I don't code in TS I'm not sure how to fix this issue.  The error I'm getting is below.

```
FAIL Components/Instructions/__tests__/instructions.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ../../node_modules/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/index.js:3
    import listenToKeyboardEvents from './lib/KeyboardAwareHOC'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1157:58)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/native-base/src/basic/Content.js:5:1)
```

Here is my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = [ "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript" ];
  const plugins = [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" ];
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

I have the following in my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js",
      "!**/jest.setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

I added the TS dev imports to try and fix the TS errors but it did not work.

Comment: Based on the log, it's written in `esm` style which is supposed to be re-compiled along side with other packages in the pattern

Comment: @tmhao2005, so how would I fix that?  Would I have to rewrite those module in plain JS?

Comment: You would try to add above package (`@codler`) into your current pattern: `node_modules/(?!@codler|(jest-)?react-native...`

Comment: @tmhao2005 that fixed it.  Thanks! I've been working that for a few days.  It's m first time using Jest.